# how to connect to cqcm by using pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc, clearquest

1. I was trying to connect to clearquest by using pyodbc and getting the following error...

connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=ClearQuest;PWD=systest1')
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

1. When i tried to print datasources available in the system then the following available datasources are printing.

{'MS Access Database': 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)', 'dBASE Files': 'Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)', 'Excel Files': 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)'}

Can anyone help me with this error??

Comment: Have you defined a "ClearQuest" DSN in the "ODBC Data Source Administrator" ?

Comment: We dont have clearquest DSN as of now with the ODBC Data Source Administrator. is there any workaround possible in the absense of clearquest DSN??

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a DSN defined in the "ODBC Data Source Administrator" then you must provide all connection information in the connection string: driver name, host name, etc.

Refer to [DSN-less Connections](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings#DSN-less_Connections) in the pyodbc documentation. It doesn't have specifics for ClearQuest, though.

I have no experience with ClearQuest so you should have a look at its documentation. A quick search gave me this:

- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rentrpt/v1r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.raer.help.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_configodbcjdbc.html
- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rentrpt/v1r1m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.raer.help.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_configodbcjdbc.html